# Who and How initialize the Interface in Dependence Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-2.0, ioc-container

For Asp.Net Core Dependence Injection, I know we register the dependence into `IServiceCollection`, and use `IServiceProvider` to get the instance.

I am wondering the code which register and initialize the `IServiceCollection`.

For Interface Injection, why did it know get the instance from the ServiceCollection? Which code implement this feature?

I want to know the global controller who and how control this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create ASP.NET Core project, the following code is generated for `Program.Main()`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

The instance of `IServiceCollection` is created inside `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` and then is passed to `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` call.

If you want to track the calls chain in ASP.NET Core source code, here it is (links to source code on github included):

[WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/35351b2677ea47a3ed69e99e4b8ddb68ab28b86d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L207) calls `WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseDefaultServiceProvider()` extension method:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()

        .UseIISIntegration()
        // ...
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
        {
            options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        });

        // ...

    return builder;
}
```

[WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseDefaultServiceProvider()](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b783d504ffe1c4df75c2f0f722fdcd9d8815d86b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L101) calls `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices()` method:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseDefaultServiceProvider(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action<WebHostBuilderContext, ServiceProviderOptions> configure)
{
    return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var options = new ServiceProviderOptions();
        configure(context, options);
        services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>>(new DefaultServiceProviderFactory(options)));
    });
}
```

[WebHostBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b783d504ffe1c4df75c2f0f722fdcd9d8815d86b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L265) eventually creates the instance of `ServiceCollection` and calls `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method (through stored action):

```
private IServiceCollection BuildCommonServices(out AggregateException hostingStartupErrors)
{
    //  ...

    // Creation of `ServiceCollection` instance
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    //  ...

    foreach (var configureServices in _configureServicesDelegates)
    {
        configureServices(_context, services);
    }

    //  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm having this problem. When i call by Postman my service i get the Internal Server Error, but, when I comment the constructor of controller work. I did: In the Startup.cs i add my interface and the implementation. In the constructor i did: **private readonly interface varinterface** and i injected in the constructor. It is a Post method. When i run by Postman, i get this error: Internal Server: What am i wrong?

Comment: Seems like you haven't registered dependencies that you inject in controller constructor. Check exception message, it will provide more details. You could also post a new question with the code provided.

Comment: Well, the error is just Internal Server Error(500) . I putted break point on Controller, but doesn't break. In the Startup class i registered in the ConfigureServices method this way: `services.AddScoped<IOptOutService, ClientUnsubscribe>();` and my controller i injected by constructor and i declared a private readonly my variable, i said in other comment. I don't know what to do

Comment: I solved my issue. The problem was in the class was implement my interface. Thanks CodeFuller.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement already provided answer, outside of asp.net-core, the DI framework can be used on its own,  separately, as it is a completely decoupled module.

[Essential .NET - Dependency Injection with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx)

```
public static void Main() {
    IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
    var application = new MyApplication(serviceCollection);

    // Run
    // ...
}

static private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new Logging.LoggerFactory();
    services.AddInstance<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);

    //...
}
```

The only difference is that now you have to create the collection on your own instead of the framework doing it for you as part of its pipeline.

From comments,

> It bears mentioning that an ASP.NET Core app is nothing but a console app, which therefore explains why you can use `IServiceColleciton` in a basic console app as well, or anywhere else you like, for that matter.

Comment: It bears mentioning that an ASP.NET Core app is nothing but a console app, which therefore explains why you can use `IServiceColleciton` in a basic console app as well, or anywhere else you like, for that matter.

Comment: @ChrisPratt added wholesale :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it on .net core 2.2:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleAppDependencyInjection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = ConfigureContainer();
            var service1 = serviceProvider.GetService<Service1>();
            var service2 = serviceProvider.GetService<Service2>();

            Debug.Assert(service1 != null);
            Debug.Assert(service2 != null);
        }

        static IServiceProvider ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(services);
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<Service1>();
            services.AddSingleton<Service2>();
        }
    }

    public class Service1
    {
        public Service1()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Service2
    {
        Service1 service1;
        public Service2(Service1 service1)
        {
            this.service1 = service1;
        }
    }
}
```